# Ajax post xmlhttprequest "processing"

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I've got this code:

```js
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
      var return_data = hr.responseText;
   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
     }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

```css
<?php 
echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', says the PHP file';
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">  <br><br>
Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"> <br><br>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I only get "processing" in the browser when running the code. Is there anything wrong? I am running it on XAMPP, if that might be a part of the problem. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Is there any error in the Javascript console? Do you see the response in the Network tab?

Comment: It says "status code 200: OK" so and I guess it should be status code 200?

Comment: That's the correct status code. Do you see the `Thank you` message in the response?

Comment: Where should that be displayed? In the browser-window? Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: In the DevTools Network tab. There should be sub-tabs Headers, Preview, Response, etc.

Comment: Solved it! Didn't have "localhost" before the URL. Thanks for the help.